# Singleton Java class can have static constant variable ? Sonar lint error

Tags: java, singleton, constants, static-analysis, sonarlint

In Java singleton class, I want to make a final constant like below code.

1. `private final int threshold = 3;`  // Noncompliant Code Example by Sonal lint
2. `private static final int THRESHOLD = 3;` // Compliant  code by Sonarlint

My question is, why singleton class should have the `static` keyword in a `final` `int`/`string` constant as this class has only one instance?

Comment: You're just not respecting the naming conventions. Only static final variables are supposed to be in ALL_CAPS. A final instance field, whether it's in a singleton or not, is camelCased.

Comment: @Pshemo I am not sure but I am expecting the answer.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree, My question is specific to sonarlint error only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably a caveat that Sonar Lint can't recognize. It's pretty hard to recognize a singleton with static analysis, so they just opted to ignore this caveat and issue a warning anyway.

While theoretically you're right (there's just one instance, so the constant will be declared only once anyway), you may be better off saving future maintainers of this code the confusion (and the need to configure Sonar to ignore this warning), and just define it as `static` too. You also may gain a minute memory consumption improvement if the compiler actually inlines it, which AFAIK, it only does with `static final` members.

Comment: Seems meaningful answer to me.

Answer (score 4):

This is an ordinary declaration of a constant in java.

```
private static final int THRESHOLD = 3;
```

It means that all the instances of your class will access *the same* field.

When you declare it like `private final int THRESHOLD = 3;` this means that every instance of your class will have *its own copy* of `THRESHOLD` field. It does not make any sense to declare it non-static when you immediately initialize it:

```
private final int THRESHOLD = 3;
```

Declaring non-static final fields makes sense when you initialize them in constructor. Thus all the instances have the same constant field with different values:

```
private final int threshold;

protected YourConstructor(int threshold){
    this.threshold = threshold;
}
```

Just follow Sonarlint's advice and declare it as a `static` constant.

Comment: My class is singleton, it means there is only one instance. It seems above code is for Normal class not singleton because it has public constructor.

Comment: @Ashutoshg Well, it's just an example. In your case the code analyzer cannot guarantee you'll have the only instance. Theoretically later you may want to convert your `singleton` to a `multiton`. So Sonarlint prevents future bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Sonarlint is not sure you're declaring a singleton. It tries to avoid hypothetical bugs in future.